# Tomcat not loading new images from context path after server is already started

Tags: java, tomcat

Inside `server.xml` of my tomcat folder, i have a virtual folder under `<Host>` tag:

`<Context docBase="C:\app_files\" path="/app_files"/>`

So i can access files from inside this folder through the url: http://localhost:8080/app_files/some_file.jpg

But this only works if the image or file was already there BEFORE the server was started. If i go to a URL pointing to an image created after the server was started, it gives the 404 error. After restarting the server, the image loads correctly.

How to sove this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually managed to do what i wanted without using the Context on the server.xml.
It's based on the [BalusC's solution](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2009/02/fileservlet-supporting-resume-and.html) to serve static files through servlets 
Here's how:

- First, i created an environment variable in my system *(can be done in every os, just google for "how to create environment variable on windows, linux, etc")*, called **MANAGEMENT_FILES**, the variable value in my case was **c:/management_files/**
- Then, on the method that creates the image that should be shown to the user, i save the image on this folder *(which is the value of the environment variable from the previous step)*:

```
public String imageUrl;

public void createAndShowImage() {
    try {
        String imageName = "/nice_images_folder/cool_image.jpg";
        File imageFile = new File(System.getenv("MANAGEMENT_FILES") + imageName);
        //Here goes your logic to create the file
        createImage(imageFile);
        //Here i use a fixed URL, you can do it as you see fit
        this.imageUrl = "http://localhost:8080/MyCoolApp/" + CoolFileServlet.BASE_URL + imageName + "?delete=true";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

- And this is the servlet you have to create, this servlet returns the image or any other file that you put inside the folder:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URLDecoder;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(name="CoolFileServlet", urlPatterns={CoolFileServlet.BASE_URL + "*"})
public class CoolFileServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "/shiny_happy_files/";

    private static final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 10240;

    private String filePath;

    public void init() throws ServletException {
        this.filePath = System.getenv("MANAGEMENT_FILES");
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        String requestedFile = request.getPathInfo();

        if (requestedFile == null) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND); // 404.
            return;
        }

        File file = new File(filePath, URLDecoder.decode(requestedFile, "UTF-8"));

        if (!file.exists()) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND); // 404.
            return;
        }

        String contentType = getServletContext().getMimeType(file.getName());
        if (contentType == null) {
            contentType = "application/octet-stream";
        }

        response.reset();
        response.setBufferSize(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
        response.setContentType(contentType);
        response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"");

        BufferedInputStream input = null;
        BufferedOutputStream output = null;

        try {
            input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
            output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream(), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
            int length;
            while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
        } finally {
            close(output);
            close(input);
            try {
                if ("true".equals(request.getParameter("delete"))) {
                    if (!file.delete()) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("File could not be deleted");
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void close(Closeable resource) {
        if (resource != null) {
            try {
                resource.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Notice that you can pass the parameter delete=true in the url when it is accessed, to delete it right after it is recovered (in cases when it will not be needed anymore).

In my case i needed to show the image on the page after the user performed some action, so all i had to do was show the image url:

```
<h:graphicImage url="#{myManagedBean.imageUrl}"/>
```

That's it, you can serve any type of file with this servlet, and it will return the file you want, instantly, and the file will remain active between server restart/redeploy (if it was not deleted through `delete=true`.

Answer (score 0):

try to add the attribute `autoDeploy="true"` to your context configuration, this will tell catalina to monitor your docbase location for changes

Comment: Didn't work, apparently this only work for java classes

Comment: @MateusViccari yes you are right, check my edit, i tested it and it works.

Comment: using `autoDeploy=true` also didn't work, the server still returns 404

Answer (score 0):

If you use Tomcat application manager you can undeploy/deploy your single application without restarting the whole server (and without impact on other webapps) or, more brutally, you can replace the desired war from the webapps dir (again undeploy/deploy will ensue). If you have to guarantee uptime for your application even in this case you have to go with parallel deployment ([here a guide for tomcat 8](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html#Parallel_deployment))

Comment: No, don't want to manually do anything, i want tomcat to automatically show the images without need to do anything at all, i need this because the images are created when the user execute some action on the website, so the images are created dynamically, and the image should be displayed to the user right after that.

Comment: @MateusViccari take a look at https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-reload#context -> Hot Reload with WatchedResource

Comment: No, unfortunately it didn't work, tried to put the folder inside WatchedResource but the 404 error still shows up for images created after server is started.

Answer (score 0):

If you care for a different approach, you can also do this by mapping a function in a controller that returns a IOUtils object while specifying the media type, then calling the function's URL in your img's src.

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="/load_photo", params = {"myPhoto"}, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
public byte[] loadPhoto(@RequestParam(value = "myPhoto") String myPhoto) throws IOException {
    
    File file = new File(servletContext.getRealPath("")+Constants.PATH_TO_FILE+myPhoto);
    
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    return IOUtils.toByteArray(fis);
}
```

Then you call your img in your JSP:

```
<img class="photo" src="/app/controller/load_photo?myPhoto=${myPhoto}">
```

With this, you can serve dynamically generated images.